# Uncaught module {} not found

Tags: cordova

Have recently tried my hands at creating a plugin using the cordova CLI 3.5.1.

The plugin was created and added to a project.  However, on execution and trying to create a instance of the plugin I am recieving the following error

uncaught module my_module not found.

```
<pre>
─── com.org.cordova.plugins.HttpRequestPlugin
    │   .fetch.json
    │   plugin.xml
    │   README.md
    │
    ├───src
    │   └───android
    │       │   HttpRequestPlugin.java
    │       │
    │       └───libs
    │               wikitudesdk.jar
    │
    └───www
            HttpRequestPlugin.js

</pre>
```

Also using the following code for creation of the instance.

`var httpRequestPlugin = cordova.require("com.northgate.cordova.plugins.HttpRequestPlugin.HttpRequestPlugin");`

This line itself throws the error as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine with the plugin and it's structure.
We need to ensure two things over here in such a scenario.

1. Ensure to add the you plugin's js file into the www/index.html
2. Also you can initialize the plugin only once the cordova's on device ready event has got triggered.  Perfoming any intialization before that would reuslt in the above error since cordova.js is not yet initialized and hence its method .exec is not available.

I believe that the plugins that have been created and available like the wikitudeplugin does this inclusion of .js file at runtime, hence it is not required to include these files manually.

If there are any other views on the answer posted please feel free to share.

Comment: I'm trying to change the cordova device plugin adding a demo.js file to the browser platform. How I do to add the demo.js file to DeviceProxy.js file??.. if I add require('demo.js') i have this error: Uncaught module /plugins/org.apache.cordova.device/src/browser/demo.js not found